# Why the value function in js is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, null

First I created a input element which will take the text input from the user ......
`<input style=" font-size: 12 px;" type="text" name="text" id="txt">`

Then to this I used some javascript to get the value of the text that the user gives as an input for that I write the below code....
`const text= document.querySelector('#txt').value console.log(text)`

But with this I am not getting any kind of value actually I am just getting an empty null value in the console can anyone please point out the mistake in the code ...

Comment: when the page loads, the input will be empty, so that's what the console.log is outputting

Comment: i agree bravo..by default your txt input box will be empty so there will be no output in console.log and if at all you need to console the input value than you has to use function in java script

Comment: `const text = document.getElementById('txt'); text.addEventListener('input', () => { console.log(text.value); });`

Comment: can u add ur code to show how u added the js to ur html

Comment: If you want to see in your console log what the user write in the input field you have to attach it an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the input that a user has typed you need to add an event listener to the jnput element or to an associated submit button.

This snippet gives a simple example. It executes your Javascript when the user hits enter:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#txt');

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(input.value);
});
```

```html
<input style=" font-size: 12 px;" type="text" name="text" id="txt">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you wrap your input into a form. Then, when the form has been submitted, you will be able to print the input text content. Please, check this [example](https://codepen.io/maremarismaria/pen/PoOvPMq) I made on codepen:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const text = document.querySelector("#txt").value;
 console.log(text);
};

const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit);
```

Also, you can get the value from the input text when it changes via the "change" event if you do not want to use a form. For example:

```
const onChange = (e) => {
 const text = e.target.value;
 console.log(text);
};

const input = document.querySelector("#txt");
input.addEventListener("change", onChange);
```

If this example does not satisfy what you want to achieve, please let me know ;).

Comment: Sorry to tell you but this didn't worked the console is still showing null...Do you have any other alternative to this :(

Comment: Can you please share a codepen with your code?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried something simple by using html onkeyup/onchange events?

```js
var handlerFunction = function() {
const text = document.getElementById("txt").value;
console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<input style=" font-size: 12 px;" type="text" name="text" id="txt" onkeyup="handlerFunction()">
```